# How to change the shapes for ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a Difference in Difference method, I have come up with the following data:

```
df <- structure(list(Class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("PovCon", 
"PovDeCon"), class = "factor"), After_2015 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Before 2015", "After 2015"), class = "factor"), 
    mean_VLP = c(16.5314094033954, 25.3785125225305, 22.4646340695607, 
    19.5147929056452), se_duration = c(3.72103200892531, 8.17273164333138, 
    4.03966402631034, 2.56248212580638), upper = c(23.824632140889, 
    41.39706654346, 30.382375561129, 24.5372578722257), lower = c(9.23818666590181, 
    9.35995850160102, 14.5468925779924, 14.4923279390647)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), groups = structure(list(
    Class = structure(1:2, levels = c("PovCon", "PovDeCon"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

For the graphical presentation, I used the following codes:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = After_2015, 
                          y = mean_VLP, 
                         color = Class)) +
   geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), size = 1) + 
   geom_line(aes(group = Class))
```

[image: Diff and Diff]

Now, as per the requirement of a journal, I would need to have everything in black and white, no color!

Hence, I would ideally like to get two different shapes for the two `Class` and different linetypes which connect the two corresponding data points.

I used the following code to change the lines:

```
ggplot(plot_data_VLP, aes(x = After_2015, 
                          y = mean_VLP, 
                          shape = Class,
                          linetype = Class)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), size = 1) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = Class)))
```

How do I change the shape with upward and downward triangles?

Please help, and thank you for your time.

[image: Diff and Diff, B/W]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get different shapes you have to map on the `shape` aesthetic:

```
library(ggplot2)

base <- ggplot(df, aes(
  x = After_2015,
  y = mean_VLP,
  linetype = Class
)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, shape = Class), size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Class))
base
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: To get upward and downward triangles you could use a manual scale where for the shapes I use some UTF8 (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+25A0):

```
base + scale_shape_manual(values = c("\u25B2", "\u25BC"))
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds great! I edited my question to reflect the input you gave. Now, two things: 1) I need to specify shapes as upward and downward triangles (fill =black). how do I go about that? and 2) what is the difference between where you specified the shape vis-a-vis I did? Thanks @stefan

Comment: Hi Tathagato. In general it's not a good idea to change your original post after you get an answer. Be it as it is I'm not 100% sure about your final result but see my update for an approach to get downward and upward triangles.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan! I will be mindful of your comment. Now with all these changes, it works great!